# Agora.io - Stream displayed in only half of my container and the other half is black

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, agora.io

I am streaming a local/remote stream in a div but it is not showing in full div. Half of the div area is showing black and the other half is showing video. If I try to include controls the full video is showing, but the controls are displayed in reverse.

I need to display full video stream within the full div with controls by default.

[Image example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vx1W.png)

Comment: Could you please add some code and screen shot to better explain the question? Thanks!

Comment: added the image, i am including the steam and calling this.stream.play

Comment: do you see any errors in the console log? Can you please update the question to include the CSS code you are using?